# configure memchaced in codeigniter 2.1.0

Tags: codeigniter, memcached, codeigniter-2

i am new to codeigniter, can any one help me to how to configue Memcached in `codeigniter 2.1.0`, or any detailed notes with examples. i really need it please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did that, i used below code:

$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->cache->memcached->save('foo', 'bar', 10);
for Memcached but it dosen't work..i don't where i am making mistake

Comment: it says that,memcached.php configuration file, located in the application/config/ directory. But is didn't find that file in my config directory.

Comment: OP's right, this is still missing from the documentation. The page for caching has info about the fact that it supports memcached but does not provide a sample config (and the package does not either), it just mentions it.

Answer (score 4):

May be this would help you:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180005